# Index load_source'd Python module in KDevelop

Tags: python, python-import, kdevelop

The [Walabot API](http://api.walabot.com/_pythonapi.html#_moduleinit) tells me to

```
from imp import load_source
WalabotAPI = load_source('WalabotAPI','/usr/share/walabot/python/WalabotAPI.py')
```

but the KDevelop IDE (version 5.1.0) doesn't index the module, so it's code auto-complete and navigation won't work for `WalabotAPI`.

How can I make KDevelop tell to index the file; or alternatively, import the python module in a way that the KDevelop indexer understands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `WalabotAPI.py` somewhere in the module search path, or simply in your source tree, and do a normal `import WalabotAPI`.

KDevelop never* cares about the value of anything - `'/usr/share/walabot/python/WalabotAPI.py'` is just "a string" - so this method of loading modules is unlikely to be supported anytime soon.

*except when subscripting tuples with an integer literal, which is common and useful enough to get special-cased.